# How to trace a function to Tkinter spinbox

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I bind Tkinter Spinbox with a function `updateVal` to track changes on Spinbox and update a global variable `val`?

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def updateVal(*args):
    global val
    val =w.current()
    print val

w = Spinbox(master, from_=1, to=31)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to use a global variable as the spinbox's internal variable:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
val = IntVar()
w = Spinbox(master, from_=1, to=31, textvariable=val)
w.pack()
mainloop()
```

If you really want to do it with a function, use the command argument:

```
w = Spinbox(master, from_=1, to=31, command=updateVal)
```